# Build APK 64 Bit Target SDK 28

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I am trying to upload my apk on Google Play Console, however, I am facing the following two issues.

1. Your app currently targets API level 27 and must target at least API level 28 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance.
2. Native platforms - armeabi-v7a

**For the Issue 1**: I believe that I need to use `android.sdk = 28` in the `buildozer.spec`, hence I changed it. On running the `buildozer android release` it says the following

`# WARNING: Config token app android.sdk is deprecated and ignored, but you set value 28`

**For the Issue 2**: I have changed `android.api = 28` and `android.arch = arm64-v8a`. but when I build and upload the APK on Google Play Console, it says
Native platforms : armeabi-v7a

Please assist me Guys!

Comment: You don't need to target SDK 28, and (per the message) that setting is ignored. The SDK version is unrelated to the api target version.

Comment: For the arch problem, does it still appear as an armeabi-v7a apk if you clean the build and run it again? There was a bug relating to build caching that you might be hitting, I think it's fixed in p4a master (and probably latest release).

Comment: I had the same issue with the api, i solved it by updating and chaging the `android.api =` to 28 in the buildozer.spec file and then it worked somehow. But whenever i change `android.arch = arm64-v8a` even though its `arm64-v8a` in the buildozer.spec it's still builds it for `armeabi-v7a`(32bit)